# Liquibase Offline : Wrong driver for the given database URL

Tags: maven, liquibase

I am trying to just generate the SQL scripts for a Mysql database. For that, I am using the maven liquibase plugin with the udateSql goal:

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.liquibase</groupId>
            <artifactId>liquibase-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.5</version>
            <configuration>
                <propertyFile>src/main/resources/liquibase/liquibase.properties</propertyFile>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>process-resources</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>updateSQL</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

That works fine with the liquibase.properties file configured to access an already running MySql server:

```
#liquibase.properties
driver: com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
classpath: lib/mysql-connector-java-5.0.5-bin.jar
url:jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mydb?createDatabaseIfNotExist=true
username: root
password: pass
changeLogFile:changelog-master.xml
logLevel: finest
```

However, I want to just generate the scripts **without** a running DB. For that, I want to use the offline database feature. In theory, a `liquibase.properties` like this would suffice:

```
#liquibase.properties
url:offline:mysql?catalog=mydb
changeLogFile:changelog-master.xml
logLevel: finest
```

However, if I do it like that, it complains about not have a driver set up. If I add the drivers like before:

```
#liquibase.properties
driver: com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
classpath: lib/mysql-connector-java-5.0.5-bin.jar
url:offline:mysql?catalog=avisporra
username:null
password:null
changeLogFile:changelog-master.xml
logLevel: finest
```

I get the next error:

```
liquibase.exception.DatabaseException: Connection could not be created to offline:mysql?catalog=mydb with driver com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver.  Possibly the wrong driver for the given database URL
```

Am I missing something regarding how to use the offline URL?
Thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the problem lies in the plugin version I am using. I copied the plugin configuration from the [liquibase documentation for the Maven plugin](https://www.liquibase.org/documentation/maven/index.html) , which unfortunately specifies an old version from the plugin (version 3.0.5). The offline url has been added in 3.1 . So just changing the plugin version to the newest one (right now is version 3.6.1 ), offline url is going to work without any problem. So in the pom.xml, the plugin version should look as follows:

```
            <plugin>
            <groupId>org.liquibase</groupId>
            <artifactId>liquibase-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.6.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <propertyFile>src/main/resources/liquibase/liquibase.properties</propertyFile>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>process-resources</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>updateSQL</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

And the liquibase.properties like that:

```
#liquibase.properties
url:offline:mysql
changeLogFile:changelog-master.xml
logLevel: finest
```

With this, it will generate the SQL scripts under `/target/liquibase` without the need of a running MySql server.